# Datepicker bootstrap timestamp

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, timestamp

I have a datepicker using https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#minimum-setup

My input type is Text. The input I receive will be: 
02/14/2017 3:00 PM

How can I turn this into a php timestamp? Like this: 2017-02-14 15:00:00

I want to store it in my mySQL datebase as a timestamp.

Comment: use `strtotime` it will convert string to unix timestamp. And store that in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to reformat the text.

For example:

```
echo(date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($oldDate)))
```